# native client curl cannot resolve host

Tags: curl, libcurl, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to create a NaCl module, which would perform curl operations. I successfuly integrated the naclports curl library, wrote a very simple module and hosted it on a local server, but cannot get curl to work properly. When I access the module (on Chrome 41) I always get the following sequence of errors:

```
Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
localhost/:1 * timeout on name lookup is not supported
localhost/:1 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
localhost/:1 * Curl_ipv4_resolve_r failed for www.google.com
localhost/:1 * Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'
localhost/:1 * Closing connection 0
```

main.cpp

```
#include <ppapi_simple/ps_main.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "include/curl/curl.h"

int ppapi_simple_main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl=curl_easy_init();
    if(curl){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L);

        res=curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;

}

PPAPI_SIMPLE_REGISTER_MAIN(ppapi_simple_main)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the solution was simple. I just needed to run chrome with the --allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost flag.

Comment: This solution will work when debugging, but to actually ship this you'll need to run the code as a Chrome App and request the proper permissions. You can see examples of this in the Native Client SDK (e.g. examples/api/socket/manifest.json)